# Where does LocalStrategy's function param gets its params, or how to make variable that is in async function available in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, global-variables

My code:

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//called some hash modules

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  var user_copy;
  const authenticateUser = async(email, password, done) => {
    const userr = await getUserByEmail(email).then(function(userr) {
      return userr
    })

    user_copy = userr; //I can't reach userr so I create copy of it on accessible variable.

    if (userr == null) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: "No user with this email..."
      });
    }

    try {
      //hashing part
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return done(e);
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  }, authenticateUser));
 
 
  /////////////////////Problem/////////////////////
  passport.serializeUser((user_copy, done) => done(null, user_copy[0]._id)); //In here I get error( at the under line too). It see user_copy undefined. 
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(user_copy[0]._id));
  })
}
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
 

module.exports = initialize
```

Actually if I able to call getUserByEmail outside of the box there would be no problem but I don't know where do authenticateUser get email param so I tried to finish my job in authenticateUser but couldn't find solution.

Where I called initialize:

```js
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async function email(email) {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

        found = await collection.find({ email: email }).toArray().then(user => { return user });

        client.close();

        return found;
    },
    async function id() {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

        found = await collection.find({ id: user.id }).toArray().then(user => { return user });

        client.close();

        return found;
    }
);
```

As you see there is email param but where does it take it from?

I just want to able to access userr or any copy of it. I tried too much way but couldn't find any way. There is no problem with another thing I controlled everything.

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is to assign the `user_copy` variable to the returned value of `getUserByEmail`

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//called some hash modules

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  var user_copy;
  const authenticateUser = async(email, password, done) => {
    user_copy = await getUserByEmail(email).then(function(userr) {
      return userr
    })
// this wouldn't be needed
    //user_copy = userr; //I can't reach userr so I create copy of it on accessible variable.

    if (user_copy == null) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: "No user with this email..."
      });
    }

    try {
      //hashing part
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return done(e);
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  }, authenticateUser));
 
 
  /////////////////////Problem/////////////////////
  passport.serializeUser((user_copy, done) => done(null, user_copy[0]._id)); //In here I get error( at the under line too). It see user_copy undefined. 
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(user_copy[0]._id));
  })
}
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
 

module.exports = initialize
```

Comment: Its not working. It gives "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"
That was the guy(https://youtu.be/-RCnNyD0L-s) wrote like.